# Power BI count the occurrence of a value in a measure

Tags: powerbi, measure

I'm trying to count the occurrence of a value in a measure. I wonder if it is possible? This is what I have tried so far. [EUI Yearly (kbtu/ft2)] is a measure I made.

```
EUI Count = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( df ),
    ALLSELECTED ( df ),
    VALUES ( df[EUI Yearly (kbtu/ft2)] )
)
```

It returns an error: Column 'EUI Yearly (kbtu/ft2)' in table 'df' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

Any fix to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try countx method, accept if help :)

```
CountX = COUNTX(
            FILTER(Sheet1,EARLIER(Sheet1[item])= Sheet1[item]),
                Sheet1[item])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  In (Sheet1[item]), the [item] I want to use is actually a measure. It is not a column. It return with the error wrong parameter type. Is there any way to count the number in the measure? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ya, i am using dax measure to count the occurence, definitely you can use dax to add column...